# How to do Neo4j Cache-based Sharding?

Tags: neo4j, haproxy

I've been reading Neo4j's [Operational Manual on Cache Sharding](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/deployment/high-availability/haproxy/#_cache_based_sharding_with_haproxy), and posts all over the web, however I can hardly find any detailed example on how to configure HAProxy for cache sharding(yes the one on Operation Manual is rather brief) on a real-world graph, which may contain multiple node labels.

Has anyone ever done this before? Would be lovely if you could share your experience.

---

Moreover, I'm a bit confused on the mechanism of the way to shard the graph using HAProxy. How do sub-graphs get cached on certain slaves, merely by providing rules in HAProxy? It surprised me to learn that cache sharding isn't handled by Neo4j.

Answer (score 3):

The goal is to send queries hitting the same region of your graph always to the same instance. This of course means that the request data indicates the region. What to use as "region indicator" is heavily depending on the structure and shape of your graph.

In a lot of cases of customer facing applications people successfully used the current user id and set it as additional http header which is then evaluated by haproxy.

Comment: That is to say, with HAProxy properly configured, the cache sharding is automatically done after restarting Neo4j?

Comment: @ToddLeo it's not so much cache sharding as it is cache affinity: by using an indicator, you increase the probability of hitting a warm cache; it's faster and reduces the cache churn because you reduce the subset of read data (it depends how much data is touched per query, though).

Comment: @FrankPavageau How does the warm cache get loaded in advance? The indicator only decide which node the query goes to, isn't it?

Comment: @ToddLeo The cache doesn't get loaded in advance, the first query to hit a particular page will load it. But once you're there, the cache state is more stable.

Comment: @FrankPavageau Does it imply that, the cache is fully loaded after all nodes get traversed?

Comment: @ToddLeo It will be "as full as it can be": if the cache is larger than the data, all the data will be in the cache, with room to spare; if the cache is smaller than the data, the cache will be full with something like the N most recent pages accessed. There's a procedure in APOC to do that, actually: [`apoc.warmup.run()`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_warmup).

Comment: @FrankPavageau Thanks Frank, the APOC should be useful. Besides, could you also give a hint on HAProxy configuring? Say I have dozens of node labels ranging from **Person**, **Company** to **PhoneCall**. What could be a **"consistent routing algorithm"** to do sharding in this case?

Comment: @ToddLeo It's not really about what kind of data you query, but in what context you query it: use a subset of the parameters of your service. The parameters include the actual, explicit parameters (like `123456` in `GET /persons/123456`) and what's already in the session (for a stateful service). That can be a user id (as mentioned by Stefan), a tenant id or even a session id in a stateful service (less cache shared between sessions, though). There's no one-size-fits-all answer, I'm afraid, but the routing needs to be a function of the input.

Comment: Could you also explain the mechanism of `apoc.warmup.run()`? Does it prepares all cache shards based on how nodes gets distributed and cached in history?